# strange mobile behaviour in Elementor

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

I have an Elementor page with basically two blocks of content:

- first block is an iFrame (with content from Canva)
- second block contains 3 buttons

https://derosemethodcascais.com/newsletter-teste-2/

The buttons should appear after the iFrame all the time but on mobile they appear on top of the iFrame, and I can't understand why (the footer also gets messed up).

[image]

The code for the iFrame is provided by Canva. I can understand that this problem has to do with a "position: absolute" but I don't understand why this works fine on desktop and not on mobile.
The code should be exactly the same for all resolutions, so I don't understand what I'm missing...

Thanks!